# Selector para aplicar estilo a una letra de una palabra

Tags: css, css3, selectores-css

Quiero aplicar un tipo de letra diferente a una letra en una palabra, lo normal sería poner un span y listo, pero no puedo modificar el HTML. Tengo un div class menu, dentro un div class logo y dentro una etiqueta de ancla  donde tiene el texto del logo. A este texto es al que le debo cambiar una letra a otro tipo de fuente.

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="logo">
        <a class="m-logo" href="#">Logo.</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Por poner un ejemplo, en esa situación debo cambiar la fuente a la segunda letra "o" que esta antes del punto y no puedo modificar el HTML. ¿Es posible realizar esto con puro CSS, sin tocar el HTML?

Comment: Recuerda que es importante agregar aquello que hayas intentado al momento

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

las etiquetas HTML solo permiten aplicar un estilo global, puedes usar un degrade multiple "Algo muy complejo para otras soluciones más simples" como el uso de span

```
<p>
  <span style='color: blue'>L</span>
  <span style='color: red'>o</span>
  <span style='color: black'>g</span>
  <span style='color: blue'>o</span>
  <span style='color: black'>.</span>
</p>
```

Si realmente estas obsesionado con hacerlo con CSS sin alterar el HTML, puedes usar gradientes lineales, pero debes configurarlo según el tamaño de tu fuente.

```css
.gradient {
  font-size: 66px;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 34px, orange 0%, orange 71px, black 0%, black 107px, green 0%);
}
```

```html
<p class="gradient">Logo.</p>
```